# Laravel nova not running the before method

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have a User model and a UserPolicy and have linked them in the `AuthServiceProvider` and can confirm the policy is being used by Nova. I also have a trait in the policy for admin users. Currently this is the trait.

```
IsAdmin.php

trait IsAdmin {

    public function before(User $user, $attribute)
    {
        if ($user->isAdmin()) return true;
    }
}
```

And my UserPolicy is something like this:

```
class UserPolicy {
    use HandlesAuthorization, IsAdmin;

    public function update(User $user, User $requestedUser)
    {
        return $user->is($requestedUser);
    }
}
```

Now in Nova I am not allowed to update Users, however if I change the update function as the following:

```
public function update(User $user, User $requestedUser)
{
    if ($this->before()) return true; // This is calling the before function inside the trait
    return $user->is($requestedUser);
}
```

This shows that the trait is working, but nova is not calling the before method. I also have all other actions `viewAny, view, delete` etc which have simular checks within them and those are using the `before` function inside the trait themselves. Now I was wondering how I could somewhat debug this issue.

Comment: Laravel Nova v4 does not mention anything related to `before()`. It should use it, but it can definitely not. I do not have the source code as I did use it I a company that I am not working for now. You can check the source code and see how it is using the policy, if in a Laravel way, or just manually getting the file and checking for the method. It is the only way of debugging it.